# GIT - Rewrite authors of commit history

Tags: git

I have a git repo that I migrated from CVS with Author name / email mismatches.  Is there a way (with out screwing up the hash of each commit) to rewrite the authors of the previous commits to unify both of these into one person?

```
Sam taco <staco@company.com>
staco <staco@company.com>
```

Comment: A better approach, if the emails are always right but the names are spelled variously, is to simply ignore the names, and if you need to write tools which display those names, look them up in your company directory server by the email address instead.  After all, most employees have just one email address, but many call themselves a whole bunch of different things.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting a repo's history like that is somewhat complicated and dangerous. However, a [mailmap](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html) seems to be the simple solution to this situation. Create a file called `.mailmap` in the top of your repo and put this line in it:

```
Sam taco <staco@company.com> staco <staco@company.com>
```

Then look at the output of `git log`. "staco" should now be "Sam taco" everywhere.